# Swap images on hover with fade

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm attempting to swap out an image on hover with a fade in / fade out effect. The jQuery below works well because it lazy loads the hover image.

The first example shows a flash of white as the original image is replaced with the new image as it fades in. The second example shows the desired fade in effect by setting the background but somehow loses the fade out effect.

HTML:

```
<img class="imageHoverLoad lazy" 
  data-original="http://decoymagazine.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/red-300x300.jpg" 
  data-hover="http://images.wolfordshop.com/images/colors/thumbs/5635.jpg" />
```

jQuery:

```
$('.imageHoverLoad').mouseenter(function() {
   var elem = $(this);
   elem.attr('src', elem.attr('data-hover')).hide().fadeIn(400);
});

$('.imageHoverLoad').mouseleave(function() {
   var elem = $(this);
   elem.attr('src', elem.attr('data-original')).hide().fadeIn(400);
});
```

Codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVQavM

Comment: whats the question if it works well ?

Comment: Have you tried using the second approach with CSS transitions to control the hover state instead of jQuery?

Comment: @DinoMyte, read the question more carefully, the problem is outlined well.

Comment: @sean I've tried using CSS transitions but it loses the fade out just the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're replacing the `src` before your transition, so there's no time to fade out. And you need to specify the `fadeOut` and wait for the animation promise to resolve before continuing:

```js
$(function() {
  $("img.lazy").lazyload();
});

$('.imageHoverLoad').mouseenter(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.fadeOut(400).promise().done(function() {
    elem.attr('src', elem.attr('data-hover')).fadeIn(400);
  });
});

$('.imageHoverLoad').mouseleave(function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.fadeOut(400).promise().done(function() {
    elem.attr('src', elem.attr('data-original')).fadeIn(400);
  });
});
```

```css
.swap-image {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.lazyload/1.9.1/jquery.lazyload.js"></script>

<div class="swap-image">
  <img class="imageHoverLoad lazy" data-original="http://decoymagazine.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/red-300x300.jpg" data-hover="http://images.wolfordshop.com/images/colors/thumbs/5635.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="swap-image" style="background: url(http://decoymagazine.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/red-300x300.jpg) no-repeat;">
  <img class="imageHoverLoad lazy" data-original="http://decoymagazine.ca/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/red-300x300.jpg" data-hover="http://images.wolfordshop.com/images/colors/thumbs/5635.jpg" />
</div>
```